# RMS minimization speed-up

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization

[Environment: MATLAB 64 bit, Windows 7, Intel I5-2320]

I would like to RMS-fit a function to experimental data `y`, so I am minimizing the following function (by using `fminsearch`):

```
minfunc = rms(y - fitfunc)
```

From the general point of view, does it make sense to minimize:

```
minfunc = sum((y - fitfunc) .^ 2)
```

instead and then (after minimization) just do `minfunc = sqrt(minfunc / N)` to get the fit RMS error?

To reformulate the question, how much time (roughly, in percent) would `fminsearch` save by not doing `sqrt` and `1/(N - 1)` each time? I wouldn't like to decrease readability of my code if my CPU / MATLAB are so fast that it wouldn't improve performance by at least a percent.

Update: I've tried simple tests, but the results are not clear: depending on the actual value of the `minfunc`, `fminsearch` takes more or less time.

Comment: Usually if something runs fast enough, there's no urgency in optimizing. What's the size of your data?

Comment: It's about 1000 points, but since it's the optimization procedure, minfunc is called about 10000 times.

Comment: There was actually a mistake in my original question: I've written `std` and meant `rms`. It's the same only if the functions are 0-centred vertically.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer for performance questions:

If you just want to figure out what is faster, design a benchmark and run it a few times.

By just providing general information it is not likely that you will determine which method is 1 percent faster.